# When arch linux boots on my mac, I can execute commands, but the screen is completely black

Tags: linux, boot, macintosh

I have tried to boot both ubuntu and arch on my iMac (21.5-inch, Mid 2010).  Both seem to boot, for example ubuntu makes its little bongo noise, and I can type zsh commands when arch boots.  But the problem is that nothing is displayed on the screen.

When I boot arch or ubuntu, apart from a bit of text at the beginning of the boot, right before the screen goes blank.  The welcome to arch linux with the green [ ok ]s doesn't show up.  However, if I wait a while, about the time it takes to boot into the zsh shell, and type reboot, or shutdown -h now, nothing shows up on the screen, but the commands work, and my mac reboots or shuts down.

I have a pc laptop with arch installed (it doesn't have UEFI though), and it seems like my mac screen goes blank when my pc screen would go blank and then the text would reappear a little smaller and better fit to the screen.  My mac is El Capitan (10.11) if that makes any difference.  I've tried booting with and without a partition ready for linux.

Is there any way to fix this, or is a mac from 2010 too old or something like that?  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Arch does not have a GUI in the install media.  In general, the older the hardware you get the best driver compatibility in linux.  Also, consider structuring your question, it is very hard to read (and understand).

Comment: Yes I know that arch doesn't have a gui installer, thats why I said I installed it on my laptop.  The problem is that NOTHING shows up on the screen.

Comment: Can you attach an external monitor to the Mac and try rebooting?

Comment: The only monitor I have is a tv, which uses HDMI, and my mac doesn't have a HDMI port.

Comment: Most tv's have multiple input ports but not all.  Note that DVI is compatible with HDMI so you can use the mini-DVI port with a suitable adapter with your tv.

Comment: If it does work from the tv, is that the only solution?

Comment: Does it show any output if you add the parameter `nomodeset` to the kernel command line?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but how would i add the parameter nomodeset to the kernel command line, just type it in after linux boots?

Comment: I'm on a mac, and I don't see any place I would add them.  I have tried using refind, but that gives me a kernel panic error, and that's the only place I could think of setting kernel parameters on mac.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by pressing alt, when the mac boots (like usual), but instead of running arch, I pressed e, and added `nomodeset` at the beginning of the line that showed up.  Then pressed enter to boot.  After installing arch linux, I had to [add that kernel parameter to refind](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_parameters#rEFInd), my boot manager, to use `nomodeset` whenever I booted to the Arch Linux I installed on my hard drive.